# Send nested JSON to server by $.ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, nested

I have a header (which creates the following section):

```
"CustomerID": "480","ParentID": 0,"StartDate": "08/07/2015",
"EndDate": "10/7/2015", "TotalCost": 0
```

and a table of details which creates this part:

```
               {
                    "selected": "true",
                    "ParentLevelName": "Parent",
                    "ItemName": "Print",
                    "Standard_Cost": "100",
                    "Client_Cost": "100",
                    "id_package": "2",
                    "Stock_Id": "2",
                    "id_Header": "0",
                    "selectedBefore": "false",
                    "id_detail": "0"
                },
                {
                    "selected": "true",
                    "ParentLevelName": "Parent",
                    "ItemName": "Social",
                    "Standard_Cost": "150",
                    "Client_Cost": "150",
                    "id_package": "3",
                    "Stock_Id": "3",
                    "id_Header": "0",
                    "selectedBefore": "false",
                    "id_detail": "0"
                }
```

when I join them together in a single Json string, it will become like this:

```
{
    "CustomerID": "480",
    "ParentID": 0,
    "StartDate": "08/07/2015",
    "EndDate": "12/07/2015",
    "TotalCost": 0,
    "SaleType": 4,
    "ClientRef": "",
    "PackageType": "Package_Type1",
    "Data": [
        [
            {
                "selected": "true",
                "ParentLevelName": "Parent",
                "ItemName": "Print",
                "Standard_Cost": "100",
                "Client_Cost": "100",
                "id_package": "2",
                "Stock_Id": "2",
                "id_Header": "0",
                "selectedBefore": "false",
                "id_detail": "0"
            },
            {
                "selected": "true",
                "ParentLevelName": "Parent",
                "ItemName": "Social",
                "Standard_Cost": "150",
                "Client_Cost": "150",
                "id_package": "3",
                "Stock_Id": "3",
                "id_Header": "0",
                "selectedBefore": "false",
                "id_detail": "0"
            },
          ...
        ]
    ]
}
```

Now, I want to Post it to server, with $.ajax , like this:
(param is the JSON string I mentioned before)

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "Register.aspx/Save",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       //data: JSON.stringify(param),
       data: param,
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (response) {
       alert("success");
          },
       failure: function (response) {
             alert(response.d);
       }
  });
```

**Update**:

```
public class RegisterItem
{
    public bool selected { get; set; }
    public bool selectedBefore { get; set; }  
    public string ParentLevelName { get; set; } 
    public string ItemName { get; set; } 
    public int Standard_Cost { get; set; }
    public int Client_Cost { get; set; }
    public int id_package { get; set; } 
    public int Stock_Id { get; set; }
    public Int64 id_Header { get; set; } 
    public Int64 id_detail { get; set; } 
}

public class RegisterHeader
{
   public Int64 id { get; set; } 
   public Int64? Parent_Id { get; set; }
   public int CustomerID { get; set; } 
   public DateTime Start_Date { get; set; }
   public DateTime End_Date { get; set; }
   public int Sale_Type { get; set; }
   public int TotalCost { get; set; }
   public string Client_Reference { get; set; }
   public string PackageType { get; set; }
   public RegisterItem[] Data { get; set; }
...
}
```

In the page.Cs

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static RegisterHeader Save(string Data)
{
    return null;
}
```

Update2: 
Error: 
 **Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an
   array**

I think the issue is I dont know how to serialize a nested object, the Error happens exactly when it's going to add Data[] to header.

Comment: What is the class look like which you are trying to deserialize this into.

Comment: I think, the service you are trying to call is trying to convert "Data" to String.

Comment: @AtulKumbhar what should I do for that?

Comment: @SarahN, I think you can get help from http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-and-Receive-JSON-objects-to-Web-Service-Methods-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx

Is explains how to pass json string to web service and get it as object in method parameter

Comment: @AtulKumbhar : Thanks, I used it , and changed my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was my argument dataType in c# code,

1)I was required to define each type specifically in serverSide, also for DateTime , I sent string and parse it in server-side code.
2)I used [decycle](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) from douglascrockford ,

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static RegisterHeader Save(string CustomerID, int Parent_Id, string Start_Date,
            string End_Date, int TotalCost, int Sale_Type, string Client_Reference, string PackageType, RegisterItem[] Data)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

Note: I couldnt find any other solution to get data in ServerSide . if anyone could make it better I would be happy to change the solution. 
Thank you

**Update:**

In the following code, I changed the argument type to Header Class:
c# code:

```
public static RegisterHeader Save(RegisterHeader RegisterHeader)
{/*...*/}
```

JQuery Code

```
  //change string to Date
  var from = $('#<% = dtStart.ClientID %>').val().split("/");
  var to = $('#<% = dtEnd.ClientID %>').val().split("/");
  var RegisterHeader = {
                id: ...,
                CustomerID: ...,
                Parent_Id: ...,
                Start_Date: new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]), 
                End_Date: new Date(to[2], to[1] - 1, to[0]),
                TotalCost: 0,
                Sale_Type: 4,
                Client_Reference: ...,
                PackageType: ...,
                Data: CreateObjArray() //this is the function which create array of Detail objects 
            };
 var myString = JSON.stringify(JSON.decycle(RegisterHeader));


//----------------------------------------------------------------

//and $.ajax function should be like this:

var param = "{RegisterHeader:" + myString + "}";

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Register.aspx/Save",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: param,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("success");
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
```